# Using sticky position with absolute together

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have this code

```css
#wrapper {position: relative;}

#content {padding-top: 100px;}

#search {position: absolute; /*position: sticky; position: -webkit-sticky;*/ top: 0; left: 40%; height: 100px; background: red; width: 20%;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>content
    </div>

    <div id="sibebar">...</div>

    <div id="footer">...</div>
    
    <div id="search"></div>
</div>
```

I need to have `#search` element in the code **after** #content element, positioned absolutely to the top. After scrolling I need to fix search element at the top of the page.

Any ideas?

I've tried to add `#search_wrap` with absolute position and `#search` with sticky position, it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: move the big height to the wrapper and you can use position;sticky

Comment: @TemaniAfif: height isn't set in real, just for this example. In real there are more elements in wrapper (#content, #sidebar, #footer, #search). Height isn't set explicitly and is unknown, but `#content` real height is about 1000px;. Instead of that, #search isn't fixed in its position (don't know where to add `position: sticky` when I need positoin: absolute too).

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I've updated my question to be more similar to real situation. Heights from CSS removed. Now I have `position: absolute;` and need to add/change for `position: sticky`.

Answer (score 2):

`grid` (again) can rescue you to avoid but simulate `position:absolute;` and use `position:sticky`;
Set both element in the same grid cell.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
}

#content,
#search {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

#search {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>content
  </div>

  <div id="sibebar">...</div>

  <div id="footer">...</div>

  <div id="search"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered doing it all in javascript instead of `css` only? that will give you more control about what you are trying to achieve:

- you can attach / detach css elements to make sure your custom behaviour is achieved
  if you are trying to mix some positions then you should absolutely investigate the javascript path.

I have written an article that wraps the javascript implementation in a hook that you might find useful. I could rewrite everything but it's easier that you check it our [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/sticky-done-the-right-way-880af0122a71).

hope my answer serves as a guidance :)